# sql calculating minutes for two dates between two times

Tags: sql, datetime, time, sql-server-2012, datediff

I have a table with two DateTimes (StartDateTime, EndDateTime) and I want to calculate the minutes between the two.

Now, I know to use the DATEDIFF() function to get this, but I only want to get the number of minutes that fall between two TIME(0) values.

For example:

```
  StartDateTime     | EndDateTime         | TimeStart | TimeEnd
2017-06-01 03:00:00 | 2017-06-01 23:00:00 | 06:00:00  | 20:00:00
```

For the above example, I would get: 
   `DATEDIFF(minute, StartDateTime, EndDateTime) = 1200`.

However, I want to only get the number of minutes that fall between `TimeStart` and `TimeEnd`, which would be 840.

How can I write my query to get this?

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Answer (score 8):

In SQL Server, `DATEDIFF()` works on time values, so you can do:

```
DATEDIFF(minute, TimeStart, TimeEnd)
```

You can run this as a demonstration:

```
select DATEDIFF(minute, cast('06:00:00' as time), cast('20:00:00' as time))
```